# Is it possible for a message producer to get acknowledgement of message receipt from activemq?

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

In my situation, a remote client is sending messages to wso2esb which is acting as a proxy to forward messages to ActiveMQ. Once the remote client receives an acknowledgement of message receipt by wso2esb, it deletes the message from its local storage. So it is very important for me to send an acknowledgement to the remote client only after ActiveMQ has received the message from wso2esb and has stored it in persistent storage. ( Store and Forward to consumers pattern ).

All I could find to read up on activemq acknowledgement is about ActiveMQ getting acknowledgement once a consumer collects a message from ActiveMQ and sends back an acknowledgement to activemq including transactions etc. But I could not find anything on a producer getting an acknowledgement back from activemq once activemq has received the message from the producer.

How do I configure ActiveMQ to send an acknowledgement to wso2esb acting as proxy producer?

Comment: Found [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ACTIVEMQ/Producer+Flow+Control) and on Producer Ack [this](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.7.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ProducerAck.html). 

Also found [sendFailIfNoSpaceAfterTimeout under systemUsage](http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.8.0-schema.html#systemUsage). 

Unsure of whether wso2esb is using these internally to return any of the Exceptions possibly thrown by the [MessageProducer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html) to the client.

Comment: Is it possible to configure wso2esb such that it returns the 'producer ack' or the jmsexception returned by activemq back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help to resolve your concern
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/01/jms-message-delivery-reliability-acknowledgement-patterns/

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question which is specifically about how to  send an acknowledgement to wso2esb acting as proxy producer. The link provides examples in java. Because wso2esb could not detect whether message has been received by JMS, I had to write custom class mediator to implement this functionality.